# How to set default value for a custom component in android?

Tags: android

I have a custom component that extends TextView. In the constructor I set the textSize to 14.

In the layout file, I try to explicitly set the textSize to 20, but the value of the attribute has no effect.

What is the correct way to solve this?

Thanks

Code

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {
    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);
    }
}
```

Layout

```
<package.MyTextView
     android:text="@string/hello"
     android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Comment: The correct way is to add your source code so that we can see the problem.

Comment: If you are setting text size in your constructor, then why are you specifying the same in the xml? The reason you are creating your custom class is to provide a default object initialized to the values that you specify in your constructor. So, set only those values in your xml which you are not initializing in your constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the attributes that you get from the XML layout in the constructor. If textSize is defined there, do not set your default textSize. see the view [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the textSize programatically, the attribute in the xml will have no effect at all!